Using Batch API through AzureOpenAI
I want to use OpenAI's Batch API . But I need to  create the client using AzureOpenAI.
https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/batch

batch_input_file_id = batch_input_file.id

client.batches.create(
    input_file_id=batch_input_file_id,
    endpoint="/v1/chat/completions",
    completion_window="24h",
    metadata={
      "description": "nightly eval job"
    }
)


As Batch API was introduced by OpenAI in April this year , no separate endpoints are provided in the Microsoft azure docs .
I believe to send a batch the client can be created using the chat_completions or embedding endpoints only which are provided by OpenAI.
But then which endpoints will be used to get status / get result / cancel a batch ?
